# Add action "page_template" not work with home page

Tags: wp-redirect

```
add_action( 'page_template', 'fw_reserve_page_template_pending', 99 );
function fw_reserve_page_template_pending( $page_template ){
    $page_template = /* My template Path */
    return $page_template;
}
```

This hook of mine work for all page but home page and front page. Any idea for me to make it work it in both home page and front page so that whenever I click on a page or lunch my site it goes to /* My template Path */

Comment: Do you have any `front-page.php` or `home.php` in your theme files? In that case, they will take precedence over the template files. Have a look here.. https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/

Comment: No I don't. The home page is default. I also do not set any in Dashboard > Setting > Reading > Posts Page, Front Page

Answer (score 0):

That is because `page_template` action really works only for "Pages". Not for blog listing / home ...

You can use [template_include](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/template_include) hook with broader impact.